# Javascript object of unknown arbitrary depth causes script to stop execution

Tags: javascript

I might receive a JSON structure like this

```
foo: {}
```

Or I might like this:

```
foo: {bar: {baz: 1} }
```

When I check the first data structure for existence like this:

```
if ( data.foo.bar.baz ) { }
```

The script stops running altogether.  I can't see any javascript errors on the browser or anything.  It just stops.  Either way tho, it would be nice to be able to do the above instead of:

```
if ( data.foo && data.foo.bar && data.foo.bar.baz ) { }
```

What's the best way to address this issue?

Comment: Heck, I can't even do this?  var baz = data.foo.bar.baz;  Nothing happens in my script after that line if foo is undefined.

Comment: how come this has upvote?

Comment: can you please post all `ajax()` the code? (presuming it's `ajax()` here...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to catch all possible errors on a deeply nested object, then you can either use the multiple `if` conditions:

```
 if (data && data.foo && data.foo.bar && data.foo.bar.baz ) { }
```

Or, if failure is not an expected condition, you can use an exception handler:

```
try {
    var item = data.foo.bar.baz;
    // operate on item
} catch(e) {
    // perform any actions when it failed
}
```

There are times when protecting a block of code with a single exception handler can vastly simplify your error handling.  Exceptions perform worse than `if` tests when the exception fires so you should keep that in mind, but unexpected failures is often what exceptions are best at handling and they can sometimes really simplify the rest of your code.

There seem to be some developers that basically never want to code with exceptions, preferring to use lots of `if` tests instead, but they are there in the language because they are very good at helping with some types of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can't affect the JSON that you are consuming, the way you are checking is pretty much the only way of doing this. Although I prefer checking for `!== undefined`.  This is purely a programming idiosyncrasy I have, since I don't like thinking of `if (object)` checking for the validity of `object`.  I always equate that line with `if(object === true)`, which isn't really the same thing from a boolean logic perspective.

```
if ( data.foo !== undefined && data.foo.bar !== undefined && data.foo.bar.baz !== undefined) { }
```

You might be able to get away with not checking `data.foo !== undefined`, since you said foo could be an empty object.

If your code would have a lot of these checks, you could do one check up front when the JSON data is received and fill in any missing objects:

```
if ( data.foo === undefined) data.foo = {};
if ( data.foo.bar === undefined) data.foo.bar = {};
if ( data.foo.bar.baz === undefined) data.foo.bar.baz = null;  // or skip this, I suppose...
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott!  I like the idea of defining what I expect to have defined but happens to not be.

Answer (score 0):

The ugly, nasty, horrible way is to use either `eval` or `try..catch`. A more robust way is to use `typeof`:

```
if (typeof foo != 'undefined' && foo !== Null &&
   typeof foo.bar != 'undefined' && foo.bar !== Null && 
   ... 
) {
    // stuff
}
```

However that only works if the final property has a value other than `undefined` (i.e. it will fail where the property exists but has the undefined value).

You can create a more accurate generic property tester to test for own properties:

```
function testChain(obj) {

    for (var i=1, iLen=arguments.length; i<iLen; i++) {

        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(arguments[i])) {
          obj = obj[arguments[i]];

        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

alert( testChain({a:{b:'b'}}, 'a', 'b') ); // true
```

but that won't check inherited properties. To check for those, you can use `propertyIsEnumerable`, but that won't check non–enumerable properties (e.g. native methods of built–in objects).

So there really is no generic solution, you can only tailor one for a specific case.